# React: ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to use async and await in my react application.

```
   onSubmit = async (model) => {
        await this.setState({ data: model });
    }
```

After adding the above code i get an error in my browser console.

> ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ],
    "sourceMaps": "inline"

}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const WebpackShellPlugin = require("webpack-shell-plugin");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = [
    {
    Server config removed

 },

    {
        entry: {
            app1: './src/public/app1/index.js',
            app2: './src/public/app2/index.js',
            app3: './src/public/app3/index.js',
        },
        devtool: "source-map",
        output: {
            path: __dirname + '/dist/public/',
            publicPath: '/',
            filename: '[name]/bundle.js',
            devtoolLineToLine: true,
            sourceMapFilename: "[name]/bundle.js.map",

        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /(\.css|.scss)$/,
                    use: [{
                        loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
                    }, {
                        loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
                    }, {
                        loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
                    }]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(jsx|js)?$/,
                    use: [{
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                        // options: {
                        //     cacheDirectory: true,
                        //     presets: ['react', 'es2015'] // Transpiles JSX and ES6
                        // }
                    }]
                }
            ],

        },
        "plugins": [
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                {
                    from: 'src/public/app1/index.html',
                    to: 'app1'
                },
                {
                    from: 'src/public/app2/index.html',
                    to: 'app2'
                },
                {
                    from: 'src/public/app3/index.html',
                    to: 'app3'
                },
            ]),

        ]

    }
];
```

I have added my babelrc and webpack config. Please let me know if i am missing something that would cause this error to appear in my browser console.

Answer (score 26):

Import regeneratorRuntime in the component using async/await:

```
import regeneratorRuntime from "regenerator-runtime";
```

*** UPDATED ANSWER *** (probably don't use above)

Import `babel` and `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` plugin:

`package.json`

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",
  },
```

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
}
```

Comment: I had an issue with reactjs.net while trying to use async/await and this worked.

Comment: This may solve the issue, but results in `error  'regeneratorRuntime' is defined but never used` lint warning.  Perhaps this can be installed as dev dependency?

Comment: @DeBraid yeap you're right. I updated the answer thanks.

Comment: Thank's after lot of search. This one worked perfectly. There is another way too i.e 

```js "presets": [ [ "@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } } ] ]```

But I think it specific to node.js but worked on client side too...

Answer (score 1):

You did not include your package.json file, so it is a bit unclear what you are missing.

Assuming you have `@babel/polyfill` as a dependency in your package.json file, is it possible that you are not specifying:

`import '@babel/polyfill'`

in your React file (such as index.js)?

Answer (score 1):

Adding polyfills from `create-react-app` worked for me.

```
yarn add --dev react-app-polyfill
```

Then add the following lines to `webpack.config.js`

```
entry: {
  app: [
    'react-app-polyfill/ie9', // Only if you want to support IE 9
    'react-app-polyfill/stable',
    './src/index.jsx',
  ],
},
```

See more examples on the [react-app-polyfill GitHub page](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-app-polyfill).