# How to use async await with webpack and typescript in react?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm getting this error: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

My babel.config.js file:

https://www.codepile.net/pile/XqDxeAq6

My webpack.config.js file

https://www.codepile.net/pile/5ndebjVq

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Babel 6 regeneratorRuntime is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined)

Comment: No, i did what it tells but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Install the runtime dependency:

```
npm i --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-runtime
```

Add the plugin to your babel configuration:

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
}
```

[Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61755999/uncaught-referenceerror-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-in-react)

Comment: where specifically? because i'm using webpack